# JSON API relationships with moshi

Tags: android, json, json-api, moshi

I'm having this response JSON that theorically follows the JSON API specs. I'm trying to parse with the [moshi-jsonapi library](https://github.com/kamikat/moshi-jsonapi) but I don't know how to parse the `some_objects` relationship. In the `SomeType` class I have a member `HasMany<SomeObject> someObjects` and the class `SomeObject` is annotated in a proper way:

```
@JsonApi(type = "some_objects")
public class SomeObject extends Resource {
//....
}
```

But, after doing the parsing, I'm getting the `someObjects` member as null. Anyone knows why?

The JSON is that one:

```
  "links": {
    "self": "someurl/params"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "some_type",
      "id": "12345",
      "attributes": {
        "attr1": 1,
        "attr2": 2,
        "attr3": 3
      },
      "relationships": {
        "some_objects": {
          "data": [
            {
              "type": "some_objects",
              "id": "1"
            },
            {
              "type": "some_objects",
              "id": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "some_objects",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "id": "1",
        "parentId": "1"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "subobjects": {
          "data": [
            {
              "type": "subobjects",
              "id": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
    }
    {
      "type": "subobjects",
      "id": "2",
      "attributes": {
        "metadata": {
            "code": "AA"
        },
        "id": "2",
        "parentId": "1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "total": 1,
    "totalCount": 1,
    "correction": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem was the name of the member, after changing `someObjects` by 'some_objects' it worked like a charm.